# block countries from shipping to them in WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to block certain countries in woocommerce that we don't ship to. For example, we don't ship to China, so I want to make sure that on checkout, when the select china as their country it won't allow them to continue to payment unless they select another country we do ship to. I feel like this option is somewhere in Woocommerce under shipping but I really can't find it. Thank you to everyone for your help.

Comment: on the Setting page of WooCommerce, there is an option "Selling location(s)" and there you select "Sell to all countries, except for…"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can simply go to the woocommerce setting and then find the Selling location(s) in General setting and select sell to all countries except for...

[image]